# optional parameter in template function

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to add in an optional parameter in a template function... Basically a parameter that overloads the relational operator depending on the user's type. It's my first template funct so I'm pretty basic. This should sort through a vector of the user's type and return the greatest element. Something like:

```
template <typename Type>
Type FindMax(std::vector<Type> vec, RelationalOverloadHere)
/..../
```

What would the second "optional" parameter look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually this is like

```
template<typename Type, typename BinaryOperation = std::less<Type> >
Type FindMax(const std::vector<Type>& vec, BinaryOperation op = BinaryOperation());
```

So the standard comparator is `<`, but can be customized if desired.

In the standard library, the respective algorithm is `max_element` with the following overload:

```
template<typename ForwardIterator, typename Compare>
  ForwardIterator
  max_element(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, Compare comp);
```

Comment: I think default argument for template parameter of *function template* is allowed only in C++11. I could be wrong though. Let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Nawaz I know that Visual Studio doesn't allow it, but that doesn't mean anything really...

Comment: @Nawaz: g++ 4.2 doesn't accept it as well, so I think you're right.

Comment: meaning my function would need to be a class template vs. a function template?

Comment: @MCP: You can always overload the function, like `max_element` does.

Answer (score 1):

It is not very clear as for what exactly you are asking about.. But..

Here is an optional parameter for which default value is specified in case user does not provide anything:

```
template <typename Type>
Type FindMax(const std::vector<Type> & vec, int foo = 1 /* <- This is a default that can be overridden. */)
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working program showing an example of what I think you are looking for:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream> 
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename Type, typename Compare = std::less<Type>>
Type findmax(std::vector<Type>& v, Compare comp = Compare())
{
    return *std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end(), comp);
}


int main()
{
    int a[] = {1, 11, 232, 2, 324, 21};
    std::vector<int> v(a, a+6);

    std::cout << findmax(v) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: now...I am getting the error that default template arguments are only allowed on Class Templates...  Suggestions?  Is it only possible to rewrite this function (findmax) as a class?